# Responsive table scroll with CSS only

Tags: html, css

I have created a responsive table and behavior is, by default the table would be floated to right and when scrolled to left content table will start from left but have the same padding from right when the table is touching the left border.

I am not able to add margin/padding to right in that case.

NOTE: please make sure to view it in less than 420 pixels and cannot remove padding from main wrapper `main-wrapper` class

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/gjbot3cj/3/)

```css
.main-wrapper{
  width:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border:1px solid #ff0000;
  padding:0 30px;
}
.responsive-table{
  margin-right:-30px;
  margin-left:-30px;
  overflow-x:auto;
}
.responsive-table > table{
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  display: block;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  margin-left:30px;
  }
  .responsive-table > table td, th {
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    padding: 8px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="main-wrapper">
<div class="responsive-table">
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">second</th>
      <th scope="col">third</th>
      <th>column</th>
      <th>column</th>
      <th>@column</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>column</td>
      <td>column</td>
      <td>column</td>
      <td>column</td>
      <td>column</td>
      <td>@column</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>column</td>
      <td>column</td>
      <td>column</td>
      <td>column</td>
      <td>column</td>
      <td>@column</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>column</td>
      <td>column</td>
      <td>@column</td>
      <td>column</td>
      <td>column</td>
      <td>@column</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed a little bit your code but I think this is what you want to achieve (open it in full page view to check how overflow works):

```css
.main-wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding: 0 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.responsive-table{
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.responsive-table > table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.responsive-table > table td, th {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 8px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wrapper">
<div class="responsive-table">
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">second</th>
      <th scope="col">third</th>
      <th>column</th>
      <th>column</th>
      <th>@column</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>column</td>
      <td>column</td>
      <td>column</td>
      <td>column</td>
      <td>column</td>
      <td>@column</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>column</td>
      <td>column</td>
      <td>column</td>
      <td>column</td>
      <td>column</td>
      <td>@column</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>column</td>
      <td>column</td>
      <td>@column</td>
      <td>column</td>
      <td>column</td>
      <td>@column</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mjke6o7a/

I have updated your CSS in this section

```
.responsive-table > table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }
.responsive-table {
  overflow-x:auto;
}
```

Other wise you can use this method (using css border),

```
.responsive-table > table {
      background-color: #fff;
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #ccc;
  /* And so on and so forth, if you want border-ception */
      margin: 0 auto;
      position: relative;
      border: 30px solid #fff;
      border-top: 0px;
      border-bottom: 0px;
    }
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ny5jxa44/

Comment: thanks for the answer but I am looking to achieve spacing before and after the table, if you look at my example, initially the table is touching the right border, when I scroll to left, it should have same spacing as I have in the left at the begining. hope this clear

Comment: @SanjeevKumar I have updated the fiddle link, Please check...
are you looking for this?